# Expo SDK 50 update adds android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play, android-permissions

I have an Expo managed react native app. Recently i've updated the Expo SDK version from 48 to 50.

Now when i tried to upload the new android version in play store, i got the below message. It was never there before.

[image]

**Here is my package.json file content :**

```
  "name": "myabcapp",
  "version": "1.23.4",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view": "^2.0.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.4.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.23.3",
    "apisauce": "^2.1.6",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~3.0.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.41",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.14",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.2.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^10.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3"
  },
  "private": true
```

**Here is my app.json file content :**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My abc App",
    "slug": "myabcapp",
    "version": "1.23.4",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          },
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "30.0.2",
            "kotlinVersion": "1.7.10"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "./react-native-maps-plugin",
      [
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
        {
          "merchantIdentifier": "",
          "enableGooglePay": false
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-document-picker",
        {
          "appleTeamId": "M34O29V5ZF",
          "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "mode": "production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "My Abc App wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads."
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": "471576785566340",
          "clientToken": "7c51e110a70788y5418478cebdcbcf7d",
          "displayName": "My Abc App",
          "advertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false,
          "autoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
          "isAutoInitEnabled": true
        }
      ],
      "expo-localization"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#f85c70",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true,
      "androidMode": "default"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "bitcode": "Debug",
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myabcapp",
      "buildNumber": "30",
      "usesIcloudStorage": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "My Abc App wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "My Abc App uses the camera to capture and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "My Abc App needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "My Abc App needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "My Abc App usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "My Abc App usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "My Abc App uses device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "My Abc App uses your microphone while taking video of your product for uploading in listing information.",
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "UIBackgroundModes": ["remote-notification"],
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "cstr6suwn8.skadnetwork"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "v9wttpbfk4.skadnetwork"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "n38lu8286g.skadnetwork"
          }
        ]
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "AIzaSyBpEfX_PyYbLxGa07zjvLJbZefx",
        "usesNonExemptEncryption": false
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myabcapp",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "AIzaSyBpEfX_PyYbLxGa07zjvLJbZefx"
        }
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#fff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "MEDIA_LIBRARY",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "RECORD_AUDIO",
        "READ_PHONE_STATE",
        "READ_CONTACTS",
        "LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
        "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID",
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
      ],
      "versionCode": 31
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "scheme": "myabcapp",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "47c5dce0-69e9-4ebf-a637-89k9879j67j8"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-789768768767698~899798798",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-987989879879~9879879798"
  }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is happening and why is happening? Also how can i overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- The warning message you're seeing is related to the use of minSdkVersion 29 in your Expo app after updating to SDK version 50. Google Play Store is now enforcing a minimum minSdkVersion of 30 for new app releases.Your app.json file does not explicitly define the minSdkVersion, which means it defaults to the value in Expo's SDK version 48, which is 29. However, after updating to SDK version 50, the default value has been changed to 30. Since you haven't explicitly set the value in your app.json, the warning is being shown.
- The updated android configuration in your app.json

  ```
  "android": {
   "package": "com.myabcapp",
   "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
      "apiKey": "AIzaSyBpEfX_PyYbLxGa07zjvLJbZefx"
    }
   },
   "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
   "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#fff"
   },
   "permissions": [
     "CAMERA",
     "CAMERA_ROLL",
     "MEDIA_LIBRARY",
     "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
     "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
     "RECORD_AUDIO",
     "READ_PHONE_STATE",
     "READ_CONTACTS",
     "LOCATION",
     "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
     "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
     "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
     "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID",
     "android.permission.INTERNET",
     "POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
    ],
    "minSdkVersion": 30,
    "versionCode": 31
  },
  ```

Comment: I put the minSdkVersion in app.json under 'android'. Now i get "Property minSdkVersion is not allowed" message. Also i can not find minSdkVersion property in expo app,json documentation : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/

Comment: I think i need to put minSdkVersion in expo-build-properties plugin configuration???